# singly linked list c++ constructor, destructor and printing out

Tags: c++, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am a beginner learning c++, and currently making a singly linked list. I have faced some problems and I thought for a very long time, searched a lot but still do not have an answer for this code so I am begging for some help..

So this is my linked.h

```
template <class T>
class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node<T>* next;
};

template <class T>
class List {
    private:
        Node<T> *head;
    public:
        List() : head(NULL) {};
        ~List() {
            Node<T>* ptr, tmp;
            for(ptr = head->next; ptr == NULL; ptr = head->next) {
                delete ptr;
            }     
        }
        List(T* arr, int n_nodes) {
            head = NULL; 
            Node<T> *tmp = head;
            for(int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++) {
                Node<T>* node = new Node<T>;
                node->data = arr[i];
                if(head == NULL) {
                    head->next = node;
                    tmp = node;
                }
                else {
                    tmp->next = node;
                    node->next = NULL;
                    tmp = node;
                }
            }
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, List<T>& rhs) {                                                                                                                                 
            Node<T>* cur = rhs.head;
            out << cur;
            while(cur != NULL) {       
                if(cur->next != NULL) { 
                    out << cur->data << ", ";
                    cur = cur->next;
                }
                else
                    out << cur->data << " ";
            }
            return out;
        }
};
```

and this is my main.cc file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked.h"

int main() {
    int array[5] = {12, 7, 9, 21, 13};
    List<int> li(array, 5);
    std::cout << li;

    return 0;
}
```

I keep on getting segmentation fault when running the constructor and I don't get why. Where am I making a mistake? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The first obvious bug that jumps out at me is: `if(head == NULL) { head->next = node; ...`

Comment: why is that a bug? I wrote that code because only the first link that is made between head and node should be that way, and the others should be put in other way.

Comment: Think about it: if `head` is `NULL` then what will happen when you try to assign something to `head->next` ?

Comment: What does `head->next` mean to you Erica?

Comment: | data | next |
       say if this is head, `head->next` would mean what it links to, which is the next node. But doesn't head be initialized to NULL?

Comment: You're using C++, so you should prefer C++ keyword `nullptr` instead of legacy C macro `NULL` - unless you code for a pre-C++11 environment...

Comment: If head is null, it means you have to create a new node for head.

Comment: okay, so then do I just start putting in values like `Node<T> *tmp = head;` `node->data = arr[i];`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cover the issue with a pointer to pointer:

```
List(T* arr, int n_nodes)
{
    Node<T>** tmp = &head; // tmp *pointing* to uninitialized(!) head pointer
    for(int i = 0; i < n_nodes; i++)
    {
        Node<T>* node = new Node<T>();
        node->data = arr[i];
        // now the trick:
        *tmp = node; // !!!
        // you now have assigned the new node to whatever pointer
        // the tmp pointer points to - which initially is - guess - head...

        // but we now need to advance!
        tmp = &node->next;
    }
    // tmp now points to latestly created node's next pointer
    // (or still head, if no nodes where created because of n_nodes == 0)
    // be aware that this one still is not initialized! so:
    *tmp = nullptr;
}
```

Your destructor necessarily fails, too:

```
Node<T>* ptr, tmp;
for(ptr = head->next; ptr == NULL; ptr = head->next)
{
    delete ptr; // you delete ptr, but advancing (ptr = head->next)
                // is done AFTERWARDS, so you'd access already deleted memory
                // undefined behaviour
}
```

Additionally, you don't delete the head node! And if head is nullptr, you again have undefined behaviour.

Try it this way:

```
while(head)
{
    Node<T>* tmp = head; // need a copy of pointer
    head = head->next;   // need to advance BEFORE deleting
    delete tmp;          // now can delete safely
}
```

Comment: wow, this really helped! If I am getting this right, then after this for-loop finishes, the last node will be pointing to null? Am I understanding your code?

Comment: @Erica No, directly after the loop, the `next` pointer of the last node is still uninitialised. That's why we yet need explicitly assign the null pointer.

Comment: I am confused with "initializing". `head` cannot be initialized as `nullptr` can it? Other than `nullptr` how can this be initialized?

Comment: 1. Assuming we have `n_nodes == 0`. Then the loop won't be entered at all and `tmp` still points to `head` (i. e. `*tmp == head`). Then the assignment *after* the loop will initialise `head` to nullptr (indirectly, via the `tmp` pointer). 2. `n_nodes != 0` will enter the loop. Then in the very first loop run, `head` will be assigned the new node directly (without being assigned nullptr before, which is irrelevant, this assignment would get lost anyway...).

Comment: So you mean that whether or not the code gets in the for-loop or not, because tmp is just a local variable, it will be lost after the `List(T* arr, int n_nodes)` finishes?

Comment: Assume that the head pointer points to a value we call `garbage` at the very beginning. We now *could* overwrite this `garbage` right at start with `0`. If the loop enters, this `0` will be overwritten with e. g. `0x1012` assuming the node was created there. If the loop is not entered, then, as `*tmp == head`, we'll assign head `0` *again*. So the initial assignment to `0` is en vain. That's what I wanted to express... The `tmp` pointer is lost after exiting the constructor - but the changes that were done *via* this pointer remain!

Comment: Compare to the following: `int n, m; int* p = &n; *p = 10; p = &m; *p = 12;` - now what will the values of `n` and `m` be? I'm doing nothing different in my code, solely that the types of `n` and `m` are pointers themselves and I don't assign integer literals, but addresses. That's all.

Comment: oh, okay I get your point! One last bit! When printing out these elements, I originally set my while-loop's condition to `while(cur != null)` but then it won't get into the while-loop at all. As `cur == rhs.head`, why is this not getting into the loop? `rhs.head` is linked to next node isn't it? (in the instance that `n_nodes != 0`)

Comment: @Erica The printing looks correct so far. You might add a space or newline after the initial `std::cout << cur;` to better distinguish the pointer value. Did you see anything else than a null pointer? You might as well try a debugger.

Comment: I used `while(cur != nullptr)` but then it would run a infinite loop getting in the `else` line... So it would print `13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13 13  13 13 13 13 .....`

Comment: oh I figured it out! `while(cur->next != nullptr)` worked! Thanks really a lot for all this help and all those explanations and comments. It really helped me understand the procedures!! :)

Comment: @Erica `while(cur->next != nullptr)` - this will fail in case list is empty. You'd better solve by moving the `cur = cur->next;` outside the if/else (must admit: overlooked that myself...).